# How to install WebSphere 7, after installing RAD 7.5?

Tags: websphere, websphere-7, websphere-portal

Am new to RAD 7.5, where i installed RAD, but i cannot find the WebSphere server installed in it, so i might have not installed while installing RAD.So, am thinking of installing it again. So could you please help me in solving this problem.

Comment: hmm... I think, that RAD7.5 don't have WAS build in (as it was in previous versions, e.g RAD7), you have to install WAS7 separately with Installation Manager and then tell RAD7.5 where you've installed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RAD doesn't WAS installations. If you want to install WAS7, download installers separately.
Also, if you want to get support for development on WebSphere Portal 7 you need download RAD 8 and install WP7 separately too.